# Everything worked, but then IntelliJ IDEA 14.02 has turned off, and then restart the project is not run and displays the following information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intellij-idea, pid, webrick, httpserver

**Everything worked, but then IntelliJ IDEA 14.02 has turned off, and then restart the project is not run and displays the following information :**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\tools\rubies\ruby-2.1.5-p273\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) E:/work/my_store/bin/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.8 application starting in development on http://127.0.0.1:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
A server is already running. Check E:/work/my_store/tmp/pids/server.pid.
Exiting

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**in the document  E:/work/my_store/tmp/pids/server.pid.   only four digits**

```
4108
```

**I use Windows 8, how to solve this problem ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I decided all by himself. `server.pid` deleted file later to restart the project file `server.pid` again been created, I deleted it again, restarted the computer and it worked**

Answer (score 1):

Use the Task Manager to check if a server process is running. If it is, stop it from the task manager. If not, delete the server.pid file.

Comment: ** @ Yole, я удалил его, но после перезагрузки снова образуются только с номерами 5076 и проект не начнется **

Comment: Then the server is actually running. Looks like you somehow configured it to run automatically on reboot.

Comment: [2015-04-13 20:38:16] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5076 port=3000

Comment: Set up what? I don't have any access to your machine; I have no idea how your server is started.